# Meaning of the German "ersatz" in English

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, loanwords, german

As a native German I know some well-known uses of German phrases, but I was
astonished that a book from a British reporter I am reading today used "ersatz"
without explanation.

Is the word "ersatz" well-known in anglo-saxon countries ? What is the
connotation of "ersatz": Do you use it more humorously or more in earnest.
From the context it is not clear what connotation it has, how would you
use it and how do you understand it ?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ersatz?s=t

Comment: Most Americans encounter the word only in writing, and only as a historic reference from World War II, where Allied propaganda paid considerable attention to German shortages toward the end of the war. It would be interesting to find out how English speakers who read the word would pronounce it. Few, I think, would sound like the German pronunciation; like the pronunciation of _Goethe St_ in Chicago.

Comment: The problem is not that the word does not exist in English, the problem is how many people know it and how the connotation is. "Teetotaler" is also in the dictionary and yet all Americans I have met have no idea what it meant.

Comment: It is easy to find people who don’t know particular words; that says nothing. *Ersatz* just means *bogus*, but in a different register.

Comment: It's featured prominently in the book *The Ersatz Elevator* by Lemony Snicket, with the meaning of *false*, *phony*, or *bogus*.

Comment: I tend to think of ersatz in the context of makeshift substitutes for things-  We were broken down in the middle of the desert but were able to get out using our ersatz fan belt made from pantyhose and duct tape. (Don't ask me why we had pantyhose along.)

Comment: @Jim: Ah, the German meaning is fairly neutral like "substitute". So "ersatz" means generally something which replaces the original with much lower quality ?

Comment: No, ersatz means fake. Not real. Bogus. [Substitute or imitation (usually, an inferior article instead of the real thing).](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/64134)

Comment: [ersatz](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ersatz) : being a usually artificial and inferior substitute or imitation

Comment: *Ersatz* comes bottom of the list in an NGrams popularity contest when it's up against [fake,sham,makeshift,bogus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ersatz%2Cfake%2Csham%2Cmakeshift%2Cbogus&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But it's a perfectly well-known loanword for reasonably educated native speakers, even though many probably think it's a bit "twee/pretentious". Whatever - the question is Not Constructive.

Comment: @all: Ok, now I think I got the knack of it.

Comment: *Bogus* is also getting used by a younger American generation with connotations of "wrong" and "unsatisfactory", as well as ersatz. Interestingly, while I never see ersatz italicized any more, that is not true of its opposite _echt_. Perhaps this is because it's possible to more-or-less pronounce ersatz with Standard English sounds, but not echt.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: 'getting used by a younger American generation' if by younger you mean since [the end of the 19th century](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bogus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @Mitch, I think my point was that the meaning of bogus is expanding, not that its popularity is recent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ersatz has a negative connotation in English. It is definitely in contemporary usage, as in referring to chicory as ersatz coffee, or aspartame as ersatz sugar. I use it in speech, though I cannot vouch for the rectitude of my pronunciation in German. But then again, I'm not speaking German. :-) I doubt that the word zeitgeist is pronounced in English as it is in German, either.

Comment: Would have given the correct check for another answer, but there were only comments....